# SQL ALchemy created_at date keeps returning null

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an orm table called customers which has a created_at column

```
class awt_customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "XXXX"

     ....
    created_at = Column("created_at", DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    last_updated_at = Column("last_updated_at", DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    operator = Column("operator", VARCHAR(45))
```

When I try to add a awt*customer object to the database and get the return object, flask always displays the api response customer.createdat as null if I do not do the following line customer.created_*at

```
def add_customer(**params): 
    customer =  awt_customer(.....) //init here  
    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.add(customer)
        session.flush()
        customer.created_at = customer.created_at // if this is gone , the json response for created_at becomes null
        individual.customer_id = customer.customer_id
        session.add(individual)
        session.flush()
        make_transient(customer)
        session.commit()
    return customer
```

```
def register(): 
    customer = service.add_customer(request.json) // request body params
    return jsonify({
        "id": customer.customer_id,
        ......
        "created_at": customer.created_at
    })
```

Why is the created_*at null if I do not explicitly assign customer.create*d_*at = customer.created*_at

The response is essentially null if I dont explicitly do customer.created_at . Is there any reason why ?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/persistence_techniques.html#fetching-server-generated-defaults